# issues counting number of comments of each post in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use laravel eloquent to implement counting the number of comments for a single post in a laravel 8. But I'm not getting any values in the blade, its just blank in the view.

Post model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
}
```

Comment model

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Post');
}
```

Controller

```
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

public function index(Post $post)
{
    $counters = $post->withCount('comments')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    return view('app/blog', compact('counters'));
}
```

View (blade file)

```
@foreach($counters as $counter)
    <p>Comments :$counter->comments_count</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Firstly, change your blade to `{{ $counter->comments_count }}`. Secondly, give this a read [https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-withcount-get-related-records-amount/].

Comment: What do you get when you print the variable $counters in your controller? can you see any records there?

Comment: @Ballard, it returns empty. no values displayed

Comment: what is the value of $post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, change your blade to echo output.

```
@foreach($counters as $counter)
    <p>Comments: {{ $counter->comments_count }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Then change your controller to

```php
public function index(Post $post)
{
    $counters = Post::withCount('comments')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

    return view('app/blog', compact('counters'));
}
```

You are using the `withCount` method wrong. It is meant to be used on query builder, not on a single model.

This controller will now return all posts, then attach the `comments_count` to each. That seems like what you want.

---

I've also left the `$post` in the index signature, but that can probably be deleted because it looks like your blade wants all posts.

If not, then change the controller to:

```php
public function index(Post $post)
{
    $counters = Post::withCount('comments')
    ->where('id', $post->id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

    return view('app/blog', compact('counters'));
}
```

Or maybe you want all the comments from that one post, in which case do this.

```php
public function index(Post $post)
{
    $counters = $post->comments()->count();
    return view('app/blog', compact('counters'));
}
```

```
<p>Comments: {{ $counters }}</p>
```

Note that I used parentheses on the comments relationship. This is to speed up the query, as it will only query the database for the number of records, rather than fetch all the data, then count the number of records afterwards.
Also, I removed the foreach from the blade as `$counters` will now just return an integer.

Comment: Hi @JustCarty, I followed the former, it brings up everything except the comments count. That is, comments count is still blank.

Comment: @Philly Have you checked your database is populated?

Comment: yes, it's populated. I just want to retrieve the number of comments associated with each post. I think the first comes pretty close. I think its best to query for all data and count the number of comments on each. but still blank

Comment: it works now. There was an omission in the blade. Much thanks.

Comment: Done!!. Please how do I activate jQuery in Laravel 8?

Comment: @Philly jQuery is a JavaScript library. Laravel is a PHP framework. JavaScript is front end, PHP is backend.

Comment: @JustCarty...and your point is? Should I hookup CDN or download the jQuery script?

Comment: @Philly My point is that they are two completely different beasts. I can't tell you how to incorporate it into your site. Laravel uses webpack to bundle your code, so I would suggest you don't do either of the things, and instead use JavaScript imports to import `jquery` into your `resources/js/bootstrap.js`. That's all I'll tell you, because it strikes me that you have no idea what you are doing, so just read the Laravel documentation, and look into Laravel Mix, and JavaScript imports. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
you don't have to do a query for this. Just do the following

**in controller**

 public function index(Post $post)

{
     $counters = count($post->comments);
    return view('app/blog', compact('counters'));
}
**and in view(blade file)**

<p>Comments :{{$counters }}</p>
```